# auto update of web page upon update of database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, refresh, reload

i am currently having some problems. i am creating a website with a chat feature on it. as of now, we were able to update the area wherein messages would appear upon user submits a message. but we are having some problems. we used jquery so that the whole page would not reload but instead only the iframe alotted for the chat only.the chat would work properly and after a few more minutes, it would start to reload over and over again. here is what we have right now...

```
    <?php
     session_start();
     include "connect.php";
     $room = $_SESSION['room'];
     $getnummessages="SELECT COUNT(*) as messagecount from tbl_chatmessages";
     $getnummessages2=mysql_query($getnummessages) or die("blah");
     $getnummessages3=mysql_result($getnummessages2, 0);

     if($getnummessages3>21)
     {
        $startrow=$getmessages3-20;
     }
     else 
     {
        $startrow=1;
     }   

     date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Manila");
     $date = date("Y-m-d");

     // Configuration part 
     $path = "images"; // Path to the directory where the emoticons are 


    //smiley
    // Query the database, and assign the result-set to $result 
    $query = "SELECT emote, image FROM emoticons"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 

    // Loop through the results, and place the results in two arrays 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
    $emotes[] = $row['emote']; 
    $images[] = "<img src='" . $path . "/" . $row['image'] . "'>"; 
    } 

    // The line below replaces the emotes with the images 
     echo str_replace($emotes, $images, $text);

     $getmsg="SELECT * from tbl_chatmessages a, jcow_accounts b WHERE                         a.room_number='$room' && b.username=a.user_alias && a.date='$date' ORDER BY postime DESC";
     $getmsg2=mysql_query($getmsg) or die(mysql_error());

     while($getmsg3=mysql_fetch_array($getmsg2))
    {

        //$message=Smilify($subject); //Smiley faces
                print "<table name='tablechat' id='tablechat' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;padding:0px;'>";
                print "<tr><td rowspan='2'><a href='index.php?p=u/$getmsg3[user_alias]' target='_blank'>
               <img src='http://www.pinoyarea.com/uploads/avatars/$getmsg3[avatar]' width='50px' height='50px'/></td><td><font color='#333333' style='text-decoration:none;font-size:14px;font-family:tahoma;'><b>&nbsp;$getmsg3[name]</b></font></a>       <font color='#666666' style='text-decoration:none;font-size:10px;font-family:tahoma;'>($getmsg3[time]):</font></td></tr><tr><td><font style='font-family:tahoma;font-size:12px;padding-left:5px;'>".str_replace($emotes, $images, $getmsg3[message])."</font></td></tr>";
               print "</table>";    
         }


      function Smilify(&$subject)
        {
          $smilies = array(
            ':D'  => 'icon_biggrin',
            ':)' => 'icon_smile',
            ':(' => 'icon_sad',
            ':o' => 'icon_surprised',
            ':shock:' => 'icon_eek',
            ':?'  => 'icon_confused',
            ':8'  => 'icon_cool',
            ':lol:'  => 'icon_lol',
            ':x:' => 'icon_mad',
            ':p'  => 'icon_razz',
            ':red:' => 'icon_redface',
            ':cry:'  => 'icon_cry',
            ':evil:' => 'icon_evil',
            ':twisted:'  => 'icon_twisted',
            ':roll:' => 'icon_rolleyes',
            ':wink:'  => 'icon_wink',
            ':!:' => 'icon_exclaim',
            ':?:'  => 'icon_question',
            ':idea:' => 'icon_idea',
            ':arrow:'  => 'icon_arrow',

         );

$sizes = array(
    'icon_cry' => 18,
    'icon_cool' => 20,
    'haha' => 20,
    'icon_surprised' => 20,
    'icon_exclaim' => 20,
    'icon_razz' => 20,
    'icon_mad' => 18,
    'icon_rolleyes' => 20,
    'icon_wink' => 20,
);

  $replace = array();
  foreach ($smilies as $smiley => $imgName)
   {
        $size = $sizes[$imgName];
        array_push($replace, '<img src="images/'.$imgName.'.gif" alt="'.$smiley.'" width="'.$size.'" height="'.$size.'" />');
   }
   $subject = str_replace(array_keys($smilies), $replace, $subject);
  }

     ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">   </script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tablechat").load("chatlog.php");
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
     $("#tablechat").load('chatlog.php?randval='+ Math.random());}, 6000);
   });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that the code for the page that gets loaded into the iframe? If so, the problem is probably that you have the code for the timer inside it. Every time you reload the frame you're adding a new interval timer, each time that timer runs it loads a new timer and so on.

The solution is to move the JavaScript you have there at the end out of the iframe and put it in the parent page instead.

Answer (score 0):

the best way i recommend CometD for always pull,it is adavenced technology for push
http://cometd.org/